# Is it possible with aggregation to amalgamate all values of an array property from all grouped documents into the coalesced document?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have documents with the format similar to the following:

```
[
{
  "name": "fred",
  "title": "engineer",
  "division_id": 20
  "skills": [
     "walking",
     "talking"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "ed",
  "title": "ticket-taker",
  "division_id": 20
  "skills": [
     "smiling"
  ]
}
]
```

I would like to run an aggs query that would show the complete set of skills for the division: ie,

```
{

   "aggs":{
      "distinct_skills":{
         "cardinality":{
            "field":"division_id"
         }
      }
   },
    "_source":{
      "includes":[
         "division_id",
         "skills"
      ]
   }
}
```

.. so that the resulting hit would look like:

```
{
  "division_id": 20,
  "skills": [
     "walking",
     "talking",
     "smiling"
  ]
}
```

I know I can retrieve inner_hits and iterate through the list and amalgamate values "manually".  I assume it would perform better if I could do it a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe two [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) queries as shown below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_division_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "division_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_skills": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "skills",          <---- If it is not keyword field use `skills.keyword` field if using dynamic mapping. 
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the sample response:

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 490,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_division_ids" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 20,                            <---- division_id
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "my_skills" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [                        <---- Skills
              {
                "key" : "smiling",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "talking",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "walking",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great stuff.  Thank you!  I was hoping to get those included into a top level document (as described in my first post) so that I could use it in a reindex / staging query.  It sounds like I'll need to pull the data into a client app so that I can build the desired documents manually.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it is not possible to get them in the format or representation you want using terms aggregation and I doubt if you can get them using any other means via Elasticsearch DSL. I guess you'd have to collect them in the client app and manage it there to get what is required. Hope that helps!

Comment: @GlennBullock If you think this has helped you and answered your query, feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer. Do let me know if there's anything else you would want. Happy to help!